# Prove that there is a sequence of k minimum spaning trees between two distinct minimum spanning trees that each one is different in only 1 edge

Tags: graphs, trees, discrete-mathematics, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm pracitcing exams towards finals,

Given an undirected graph $G(V,E)$ , we denote 2 MST $T,T'$ neighbours if by deleting one edge from $T$ and add another one we get $T'$.

Prove : 
for every 2 **distinct** MST $T,T'$ there is a sequence of $k$ MST's such that every 2 MST's $T_i,T_i+1$(+1 on the index) in the list are neighbours and at the end of the sequence we get $T$

$T' = T_1,T_2,T_3,\ldots,T_k=T$

hope to get help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Between every two MST's there's a series of "nearby" MST's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88134/between-every-two-msts-theres-a-series-of-nearby-msts)

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalization of the [Uniqueness property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Uniqueness) of minimum spanning trees, and the proof is almost the same:

1. Note there is at least one edge that belongs to exactly one of $T$ and $T'$. Among such edges, let $e_1$ be the one with least weight. Without loss of generality, assume $e_1 \in T$.
2. As $T'$ is an MST, $e_1\cup T'$ must contain a cycle $C$ with $e_1$.
3. As a tree, $T$ contains no cycles, therefore $C$ must have an edge $e_2\notin T$.
4. Since $e_1$ was chosen as the lowest-weight edge among those belonging to exactly one of $T$ and $T'$, the weight of $e_2$ must be no less than the weight of $e_1$.
5. As $e_1$ and $e_2$ are part of the cycle $C$, replacing $e_2$ with $e_1$ in $T'$ therefore yields a spanning tree $T''$ with no larger weight, thus also a minimum spanning tree. Since $e_1\in T$ and $e_2\notin T$, $T''$ is more "closer" to $T$ than $T'$.
6. Repeat the processes above for $T$ and $T''$. Finally you will get a sequence of mimimum spanning trees between $T$ and $T'$.