# Edge exchange property of two Minimum Spanning Trees

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, minimum-spanning-tree

Given an undirected graph `G` with weight on its edges and 2 `different` minimal spanning trees(MSTs): T, T'

Then I want to prove the following:

> For every edge `e` in T that's not in T', there is an edge `e'` in T'
> that's not in T such that if we replace `e` with `e'` in T (let's call
> it T_new) then it's still a minimal spanning tree of `G`.

I think I am too close for finding the right algorithm but stuck a little:

1. I have proved that `weight(e)` must be exactly equal to `weight(e')`.
2. Since T is a tree, deleting e will result in 2 separated components, then for T_new to be a tree it must use one of the edges connecting two vertices from those different components.

**But**, I wasn't able to know which edge `e'` exactly will work. Plus I wasn't able to prove that **always** there is such an edge (I just found some requirements for `e'` that is must satisfy).

Some notes: I know Kruskal algorithm, and familiar with an algorithm in which we can paint some edges in yellow and request it to generate minimal spanning trees with maximum yellow edges (In other words from all found minimal spanning trees return the one with maximum number of yellow edges)

Comment: It's funny because every spanning tree is minimal by definition.

Comment: no? a tree is spanning, but not necessarily a minimal spanning tree

Comment: take a look at this link for the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Comment: @nirshahar "minimal" has a different meaning than "minimum". Pal GD is correct. A spanning tree is always minimal since it is spanning all nodes and is a tree. However, in old times the term "minimal spanning tree" was also used to signify "minimal spanning tree". And, it is still continuing now. (shrug)

Comment: Well, good to know the difference! However it doesn't change the fact the OP asked about minimum spanning trees :)

Comment: Yes. Agreed. :). Edit in the previous comment: "However, in old times the term "minimal spanning tree" was also used to signify "minimum spanning tree".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof. Let $V$ be the vertices of $G$. $V$ are also the vertices of $T$ and the vertices of $T'$.

If $e$ is deleted from $T$, we will get two trees. Let the vertices of these two trees be $(V_1, V_2)$, which is a cut of $V$.

Since $T'$ is a tree, if we add $e$ to it, we will obtain a cycle. Since that cycle crosses $(V_1, V_2)$ at $e$, it must cross $(V_1, V_2)$ at another edge, say, $e'\in T'$.

- Since $T \setminus \{e\}\cup \{e'\}$ is a spanning tree of $G$ and $T$ is an MST,  $\text{weight}(e) \le \text{weight}(e')$.
- Since $T' \setminus \{e'\}\cup \{e\}$ is a spanning tree of $G$ and $T'$ is an MST,  $\text{weight}(e') \le \text{weight}(e)$.

So, $\text{weight}(e) = \text{weight}(e')$.

$T \setminus \{e\}\cup \{e'\}$, which is a spanning tree of the same weight as $T$,  must be an MST of $G$. $\quad\checkmark$

Comment: What we have proved is, in fact, that for every cut $C$ and every MST $T$ of $G$,  $T$ must contain at least one edge of minimum weight in the cut-set of $C$.

Comment: If you can kindly help me prove that: "The edge e' cannot be heavier than e, or else T' would not be minimum (T' \ {e'} U {e})" From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456739/finding-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-in-graph?

Comment: You made a mistake claiming: Since ′∖{′}∪{}
T
′
∖
{
e
′
}
∪
{
e
}
 is a spanning tree of 
G. Please read my counter example here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140652/followup-to-previous-question-minimum-spanning-tree In case you delete e' and replace it with e you will get a circle which contradicts the definition of tree.

Comment: The $e'$ in my proof is not an arbitrary edge that cross the cut. It is the very edge in $T'$ in your counterexample which together with $e$ forms the circle you mentioned. Please check again how $e'$ is selected. In particular, $e'$ is part of "that cycle".

Comment: Got you, so his answer is wrong too. Can't upvote you I need 15 rep points

Comment: BTW, should we take the minimal e' not just any arbitrary one? regarding the points I don't know it show me to sign it too even though I am signed in.

Comment: In this case, I meant what I have written. "No more, No less". $e'$ is any arbitrary edge as selected.

Comment: But if you give it a thought it just doesn't make sense (sorry to say that). I mean if we have multiple options for e' and we want to build a minimum spanning tree it makes 100% sense if we select the edge with minimal weight. what if that e' you selected has greater weight compared to others which don't make a circle?

Comment: You make the perfect sense from your line of thought.  However, we have proved that, whichever $e'$ we selected (as in the proof), its weight is **always the same as the weight of $e$.** So, it does not matter at all whether we choose the one with the minimal weight, or even choose the one with the maximal weight. Because all of them are of the same weight. "Others which don't make a circle" are irrelevant.

Comment: Last thing kindly, can you give a counter example where selecting the minimal one won't work or a one that doesn't work as the other guy's answer (linked before)?

Comment: @user136396, please come to [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r_-mNvcFF7guzYLH-XISwUgxWhfr5xUgDaxR2YS_JIs/edit) for a chat.

Answer (score -1):

Add an edge to a spanning tree and you have a cycle. Deleting any edge in that cycle results in a new spanning tree.

Comment: it doesn't prove its a minimal spanning tree