# Removing and adding edges from spanning tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, discrete-mathematics

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two spanning trees. If $a$ is an edge in $T_1$ that is not in $T_2$, and $b$ is an edge in $T_2$ that is no in $T_1$. I want to prove that $T_1 - \{ a\} + \{ b\}$ is a spanning tree. I have an idea of what is happening but I don't know exactly how to write the proof. I know that $T_1 - \{ a\}$ creates a partition of the vertices, but how can I conclude that adding $b$ to $T_1 - \{ a\}$ is necessarily a spanning tree?

Comment: They also need to be with the same weight.

Comment: @nirshahar: Do you mean that $a$ and $b$ need to have the same weight?

Comment: Are you asking about spanning trees or about *minimal* spanning trees? If they are minimal then this would be a requirement. Otherwise, it is not necessary.

Comment: @nirshahar: They are only spanning trees.

Comment: Where does the question come from? As it's stated, your claim is false. You can't just take any edge in $T_2$ and substitute for the missing edge in $T_1$.

Comment: The proper formulation is probably: if $a$ is in $T_1 \setminus T_2$ *then there exists* $b$ in $T_2\setminus T_1$ such that $T_1-a+b$ is a spanning tree. This "basis exchange property" holds for both spanning trees in general as for minimal spanning trees. Related:  [Edge exchange property of two Minimum Spanning Trees](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140094/4287)

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove a false statement.
Its possible that T -{a} + {b} is not spanning tree.
Consider the below example

Lets say T1 is-

```
       1
      / \
     2   3
    /    /
   5    4
  /
 6
```

Lets say T2 is-

```
        1
         \
      2   3
     /|\  /
    5 6  4
```

both are spanning tree but if we replace edge 1-2 in T1 with edge 2-6 in T2 then it will not be spanning tree anymore.
QED

Comment: It will still be a spanning tree with that replacement… However, it will not if you replace egde $\{5,6\}$ in $T_1$ with edge $\{2,4\}$ in $T_2$.

Comment: I made a mistake. I corrected it. actually you need to replace 1-2 with 2-6